# Locking scroll of gridview

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have one gridview in my UI but it scrolls vertically I have set all the scrollbar properties as false but its still scrolling. Any idea why this is so? please help.[image]

This is my layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_im" android:id="@+id/rLayout" android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lLayoutCalendar" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayoutLeftTask" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:background="@drawable/calendar_bgnew" android:isScrollContainer="false">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none" android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar_arrow_previous">
            </ImageView>
            <Button android:id="@+id/currentMonth" android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Button>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar_arrow_next">
            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:text="Su" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="65px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Mo" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="65px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Tu" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="63px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="We" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="63px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Th" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="63px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Fr" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="63px">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:typeface="sans" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:text="Sa" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:textColor="#7e7f7e"
                android:layout_width="63px">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <GridView android:numColumns="7" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  style="overflow:lock"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:horizontalSpacing="-1px" android:verticalSpacing="-1px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:smoothScrollbar="false" android:stackFromBottom="false"
             android:fastScrollEnabled="false" android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:fadeScrollbars="false">
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you post your layout?

Comment: Otra please see I have done this.

Comment: @PoojaBohora i have face same problem . have u any solution ?

Comment: @Parag : As much I had studied,we cannot lock vertical scrolling of gridview.

Comment: @PoojaBohora below code solved the issue try this.

Comment: @parag I was having gesture on grid view control so I could not lock the move action.

Answer (score 6):

Try to add or override `setOnTouchListener` for GridView, then in onTouch method you can use code like this to make gridview not scrolling :

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: This solution solves the above problem, but creates a new one:  You can no longer cancel button presses by sliding your finger away.  This means that if you touch a button in your grid at the bottom left, and then slide it to the top right, that bottom left button will call onClick when you lift up, as if you'd never moved your finger.  The button will also stay in its pressed state while you drag.

Answer (score 3):

Use this custom gridview. It automatically sets the height and does not scroll:

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView {
    public MyGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightSpec;

        if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
            // The great Android "hackatlon", the love, the magic.
            // The two leftmost bits in the height measure spec have
            // a special meaning, hence we can't use them to describe height.
            heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        } else {
            heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is designed to scroll vertically, and I am not aware that you can stop it from scrolling. If you do not want scrolling, do not use a `GridView`.

Comment: but what should we use than?

 Let's say I want to fit grid of 8*8 square fields which will contain just one letter each, somewhere on my screen.. what should I use?

Comment: @Ewoks: Either use `TableLayout`, nested `LinearLayouts`, or create your own `ViewGroup` that implements whatever business rules you like.

Comment: use ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myGridView extends GridView {

    public myGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    //Do nothing here!!!
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    //false return 
    return false;
    }
}
```